# "AttributeError: module 'random' has no attribute 'randit' "

Tags: python

Here is the code:

```
import random
secretNumber = random.randit(1, 20)
print("I'm thinking of a nummber between 1 and 20.")
for guessesTaken in range(1, 7):
    print("Take a guess.")
guess = int(input())

if guess < secretNumber:
    print("Your guess is to low")
elif guess > secretNumber:
    print("Your guess is to high")
else:
    break # This condition is the correct guess!

if guess == secretNumber:
    print("Good job! You guessed my number in " + str(guessesTaken) + "guesses!" )
else:
    print("Nope.The number I was thinking of was " + str(secretNumber))
```

This is the problem :

```
    "AttributeError: module 'random' has no attribute 'randit'"
```

I tried to change the name of the file from "test.py" which was the first name of the file and then in "guessTheNumber.py" but still didn't works.

Comment: You want to use `randint` rather than `randit`. Notice the missing `n`.

Comment: Thanks , I wasn't paying attention .  Thank you a lot . I will be careful next time .

Answer (score 1):

Wrong spelling. Maybe what you wanted is:
`secretNumber = random.randint(1, 20)`
It should be `randint(1,20)` not `randit(1,20)`

Comment: Yas , that was the problem . Thank you !! I'm new in Python , I need time to work to get  used with it , but thank you again!!